# Lightning App - getting URL parameter

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, urlhacking, lightning

We are planning to convert some of our VF pages to Lightning apps. Some our VF pages, particularly surveys are URL parameter-driven, since we send survey links directly to users, i.e. `https://[vf_instance].force.com/apex/CaseSurvey?caseid=xxxxx`

Say we convert the VF page to an Lightning app, we would probably be sending the Lightning survey like this `https://[vf_instance].lightning.force.com/c/CaseSurvey.app?caseid=xxxxx`

**Problem:**

In VF page controller, PageReference.getParameters() contains the much needed **`caseid`**

However, in Lightning component controller, PageReference.getParameters() does not contain any URL parameters.

How can I get the URL parameter in Lightning app/component apex controller?

THANKS!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In lightning whatever attribute you define can be passed as a query parameter .

Lets take a look with sample example

```
<aura:application>
  <aura:attribute name="whom" type="String" default="world"/>
   Hello {!v.whom}!
</aura:application>
```

Here is how the result will look like

[image]

Now I will add a query parameter with value as per my attribute defined **whom** in the URL and now the result will be as below

[image]

> In very simple terms you just need to define an aura:attribute and you are good

```
 <aura:attribute name="caseid" type="String"/>
```

Comment: Good explanation @Mohith . Just an addition, it only supports String type of attributes :)

Comment: This will only work is the attribute is defined in the .app. What is I want to pass the parameter to a nested component?

Comment: Does it alos work with embedded components in custom lightning page in COmmunity?

Comment: Thanks @AllenMann for tip that the `<aura:attribute>` must be defined in the app containing your component. To pass the parameter to any nested components then set them as attribute values on the nested components like `<c:YourCmp someAttribute="{!v.whom}"/>` where your containing app declares `<aura:attribute name="whom" type="String"/>` per @Mohith's example

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149445/app-attributes-for-components/149448#149448  .Here is an example how you pass and go down the chain

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? It works but I am a bit weirded out that I hadn't seen any information anywhere about it.

Answer (score 8):

Just adding this answer for completion of the thread with the latest release. After Summer 18 release (API version 43 and up) we can utilise `lightning:isUrlAddressable` interface.

Implement `lightning:isUrlAddressable` interface and use `pageReference` attribute.

Example. - Component
Assume url is  *https://<instance>.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/<namespace>__componentName?testAttribute=XYZ*

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable">
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" description="Handler for valueInit event fired when the component has been initialised"/>
        {!v.pageReference.state.testAttribute}
</aura:component>
```

Component Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(component.get("v.pageReference").state.testAttribute);
    }
})
```

Console output will look like: "XYZ"

Comment: That works for a Lightning **Component**, but I couldn't get it to work for a Lightning **Application**

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any documented way of doing that, but I was able to do so using a hack.

The Salesforce Lightning URL is something like "/one/one.app#_______" . The blank contains some encoded value in the URL. The encoded value is nothing but the details of the Component/Page in Base64 encoded form.

Use the below code in Javascript in Visualforce to navigate to Lightning Components-

```
<script>
var compDefinition = { 
"componentDef" : "c:NewContact", 
"attributes" :{ 
      "recordTypeId" : "012xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "testAttribute" : "attribute value"
 } 
};
// Base64 encode the compDefinition JS object
var encodedCompDef = btoa(JSON.stringify(compDefinition));
window.parent.location = "/one/one.app#"+encodedCompDef;
</script>
```