# App attributes for components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

Is there a possibility to pass .app custom attributes for component in it? I've tried to use inheritance, but components cannot extend apps.

Do you know any solutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using simple attributes .Here is a sample Hello world that works

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="Test" default="world"/>
<c:Sample title="{!v.Test}"/>
```

The component code

```
<aura:component >
  <aura:attribute type="String" name="title" />
Hello {!v.title}
</aura:component>
```