# Access url parameter from lightning component Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a url link on a lightning component on customer community. When I click the link, I redirect to other lightning component.

```
<aura:attribute name="Url1" type="String" default="./commonClass?par=True?id=" description="URL to the common page." />
<li class="slds-item"><a href="{!v.Url1}">commonpage1</a></li>
```

Now, I would like to access the parameter "par" from the url link on new lightning component after redirecting. How can i do it?
I went through [Getting the URL parameter into Lightning component using the "{! paramName}" expression](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165650/getting-the-url-parameter-into-lightning-component-using-the-paramname-exp) and [Lightning App - getting URL parameter](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106543/lightning-app-getting-url-parameter), but I dont see any `<aura:application/>` to declare my attribute there.

Updated:
cmp:

```
 <aura:attribute name="int" type="String" description="Boolean from url to show Intermittent Report." />
```

controller.js:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        helper.getParameterByName(cmp,event,'int');
    }
```

helperjs:

```
getParameterByName : function(cmp,event,name) {
   url = window.location.href;
   name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
   var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
   results = regex.exec(url);
   if (!results) return null;
   if (!results[2]) return '';
   //return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        component.set('v.int', decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " ")));

},
```

It says, `WARNING: Callback failed:` in inspect element chrome.

Please guide.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a limitation, you cannot access the URL parameters in lightning components via an expression tag .

If the hashed part of the URL is changing then there is a neat event to handle and you can read what has changed

[aura:locationChange event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_locationChange.htm)

If your URL hash is not changing then you can use javascript to do this in your controller.js using below code

```js
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
  // This is url query parameter
  var value = helper.getParameterByName(component , event, 'variable');
  // Set the value, assumes you have created attribute "attributename" in your markup
  component.set("attributename", value);
}
```

and your helper.js will have a common function to read URL parameter

```js
getParameterByName: function(component, event, name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var url = window.location.href;
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)");
  var results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: side note: window.location.pathname instead of window.location.href can also be used, if you don't need the whole url

Comment: @mohit thanks for the response. is the 'variable' parameter in my controller.js thats calling helper is the attribute in url link?

Comment: Yes thats URL query parameter and I assume that you will use the attribute value as a query parameter to the URL

Comment: yes, but the attribute I use in URL is declared on the first component. When I click a URL on first component, it redirects to the new component. Now i want to access the attribute from URL in new component. The attribute is declared on different component and accessed in other component. In this case, do I have to declare attribute on both components or just on the initial component works?

Comment: Ya so once you get the value is javascript you can use component.set("attributename", variablevalue); updated ans

Comment: Mohit, i tried but its throwing callback failed error. I updated my question with the solution you suggested. Please refer to the updated part of question

Comment: I changed now check it var variablevalue = helper.getParameterByName(component ,event,'variable');//This is url query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57134/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-anurag-a).

Comment: @MohithShrivastava It worked. Some syntactical issue were responsible for error. I got it to work now. Thank you for the help.