# Does lightning app or home page have URL?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-apps

Does lightning app or home page have URL like visualforce page?
I need to create a custom page (custom styling) with its own URL.

Comment: Are you after this one? - https://yourdomain.force.com/one/one.app#/n/YOUR_LIGHTNING_PAGE_NAME ?

Comment: @BorisBachovski yes.. when navigate to the URL, it should display only my custom page. I do not want salesforce navigation within the page.

Comment: Have you tried building a custom lightning app?, the custom lightning app would not have any other components apart from yours. You can get the URL of the custom lightning app and then use it accordingly

Comment: @HemantJain Do you know how to get the URL of the custom lightning app? I can't find any reference how to retrieve the URL of custom lightning app

Comment: When you do a preview of the lightning app. You can use the same browser URL: See this link, to get an idea: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106543/lightning-app-getting-url-parameter

Comment: Another link: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000DBzIAAW

Comment: Did this resolve your query?

Answer (score 2):

Create a standalone application and shove your component(s) in there - example:

```
<aura:application>
<c:YOURCOMPONENT />
</aura:application>
```

Then you can preview it by navigating to `https://yourdomain.lightning.force.com/c/YOURAPPLICATIONNAME.app`