# What is the syntax for the Field Service Mobile App Extension config of Launch Value for a Lightning App Tab?

Tags: integration, field-service-lightning

I want to open a Lightning App Tab in Salesforce Mobile from the Field Service Mobile app.  I created an App Extension in my Field Service Mobile settings.  I configured the extension like this:

Type:  **Lightning App**

Scoped To Object Types: **WorkStep,WorkPlan,WorkOrder,ServiceAppointment**

The documentation says you can use the Lightning Page Tab name in the Launch Value field (as long as there are no spaces) so I created a Lighting Page Tab called "MyTab" that displays v.recordId.

```html
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <lightning:card title="Lightning Aura Component">
        <div class="slds-p-around_small">
            Current Record ID in Lightning Aura Component: <strong>{!v.recordId}</strong> <br/><br/>
        </div>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

The Field Service Mobile App Extension documentation also alludes to passing parameters from a FSL mobile field via the Launch Value setting "like so: **{!Name}**."

I'm trying to pass the Work Order recordId into the Lightning Page tab.  The tab launches but the record ID doesn't make it to the tab.  Tried these three "guesses":

Launch Value    **MyTab{!$recordId}**

Launch Value    **MyTab{!recordId}**

Launch Value    **MyTab{!Id}**

But the record ID does not make it to my tab.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried passing {!Id} as the launch value? Documentation states it's the name (developer / API name) of the field -- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mfs_extension.htm&type=5

Comment: Yes, tried:  MyTab{!Id} and the tab pops up in mobile app but the ID does not make it to the tab.

Comment: Maybe also try adding an aura:attribute `<aura:attribute name="id" type="String"/>`, see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106543/lightning-app-getting-url-parameter